# Convert two lists to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def dbupdate(self):
    dicDccp = dict(zip(self.dccpdate, self.dccpValue))
    dicDcep = dict(zip(self.dcepdate, self.dcepValue))
    dicDccp = sorted(dicDccp.keys())
    dicDcep = sorted(dicDcep.keys())
    print(type(dicDccp))
    print(type(dicDcep))
    for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(dicDccp.items(), dicDcep.items()):
        self.Db.dbupdate(self.symbol, self.threshold, k1, v1, k2, v2)
```

I tried to convert the two lists to a dictionary. But the types of `dicDccp` and `dicDcep` were still `list`s.

[image]

Comment: Yes, because you converted them back into lists using `sorted`

Comment: WHY ARE WE SCREAMING?!

Comment: The built-in [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function returns a new `list` object, so the assignments back to `dicDccp` and `dicDcep` effectively change them from dictionaries into that type.

Comment: Also suggest you read (and start following) [**_Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?_**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the line `dictDccp = sorted(dictDccp.keys())`

sorted is a function that takes an iterable object (such as the keys() object that you give it) and returns a list. You are overwriting your dictDccp with this list.

If you were trying to iterate through the keys of the dictionaries in sorted order you could do

```
for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(sorted(dictDccp.items()), sorted(dictDcep.items())):
    self.Db.dbupdate(self.symbol, self.threshold, k1, v1, k2, v2)
```